# Gradle Unable to retrieve local repository

Tags: gradle

I have the following setup in my build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url '/Users/me/.m2/repository'
    }
```

A library under the directory doesn't get imported into my project. I create another project with Maven and the library is imported. What is missing in the gradle setup?

Here is the file:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.3.5.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url '/Users/vewu/.m2/repository'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
  baseName = 'sample'
  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()  // <-- I need to add this one
}


dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
  compile 'mylibrary:mypackage:1.3.18'
  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}

  dependencyManagement {
  imports { 
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.RELEASE" 
  }
}


  eclipse {
  classpath {
     containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
     containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
  }
}
```

I just recognize that I need to add mavenLocal() on the repository block outside of the buildscript as well.

Comment: Isn't "/Users/me" supposed to be your home dir?  If so, that's exactly what "mavenLocal()" looks at.

Comment: did you at least declare some dependencies?

Comment: Continuing in that theme, how about you show your entire build script, and exactly what you see that is wrong, and exactly what you expect to see?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Yes, "/Users/me" is my home directory. I use a Mac ProBook. Don't understand 'what "mavenLocal()" looks at.' The problem as I state in my question is that a dependency isn't in the project library. I will post the whole gradle build file shortly.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Of course, I declare dependencies in the build file.

Comment: I solve the problem. The mavenLocal() needs to be added into another respository block.